# Podio API Creating comments with additional attributes

Tags: podio

I am working on migrating data from multiple app items into one. I was able to move all the data over but I need to move comments and files as well.

I know the API allows you to create comments from an App (which I am doing) but I want to be able to create the comment and pass the original information (message,creator,created_on).

The API documentation doesn't show what are all the "possible" attributes for creating a comment.

Thanks.

- Rico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All details on how to create new comment are here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/comments/add-comment-to-object-22340

```
{
  "value": The comment to be made,
  "external_id": The external id of the comment, if any,
  "file_ids": Temporary files that have been uploaded and should be attached to this comment,
  [
    {file_id},
    .... (more file ids)
  ],
  "embed_id": [OPTIONAL] The id of an embedded link that has been created with the Add an mebed operation in the Embed area,
  "embed_url": The url to be attached
}
```

Please note, you can't set some of comment's attributes (like: `creator`, `created_on`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw those details but I was hoping to be able to do it. This extension claims to do it. Do you know how they might be doing it? https://podio.com/extensions/51

Comment: You can create comment like "<author> commented <original comment text> on <original comment date/time>". Then information about created and created_on will be saved but will be part of comment's text