# Podio - Migrating comments into timeline

Tags: podio

This is a question for the Citrix Podio Developer team - I know it is not possible with the standard API.

Is it possible to gain additional access to the API such that I can import data and back date item creation date?

Point in case - migrating comments in from another app. I'd like to show those comments in the activity stream of the new app items exactly as they appeared in the previous app, rather than a 'cut and paste'.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do: [Podio API Creating comments with additional attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087309/podio-api-creating-comments-with-additional-attributes) ?

If yes - answer is still the same: you can't set some of comment's attributes (like: `creator`, `created_on`).